# add substract minutes google calendar api

Tags: java, maven, date, datetime, google-api

Im using google calendar api with Java 8 maven project. I want to substract 15 minutes from the date value. But I couldnt find any solution. I dont want to use 3rd party library, it shouldnt be that hard. Also I dont want to change to Calendar object or Localdatetime etc..

I couldnt substract from Date, DateTime and EventDateTime object's value.

DateTime is from com.google.api.client.util.DateTime

Just want to substract 15 min. Time values are daytime. (doctor appointments)

Thanks.

ex:

```
appdate   = 2/19/2019
startTime = 04:15 pm

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.US);
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));

        String dateInString = appDate + " " + startTime;
        Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
        DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime(date, TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime().setDateTime(startDateTime).setTimeZone("America/New_York");

        event.setStart(start);
```

Comment: Where are you getting `DateTime` class? Is that from the Joda-Time library?

Comment: DateTime class is; com.google.api.client.util.DateTime.       Because EventDateTime wants this type of input value.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `TImeZone` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate`, `LocalTime`, `DateTimeFormatter` and `ZoneId`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).The Google `DateTime` has a constructor that accepts milliseconds since the epoch, or you may convert through an `Instant` to an old-fashioned `Date` object.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
String inputDate = "2/19/2019" ;
String inputTime = "04:15 pm".toUpperCase() ;  // AM/PM is properly localized in US as all uppercase.

DateTimeFormatter fDate = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "M/d/uuuu" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( inputDate , fDate ) ;
System.out.println( "ld.toString(): " + ld ) ;

DateTimeFormatter fTime = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "hh:mm a" , Locale.US ) ;  // Specify `Locale` to determine the human language and cultural norms to use in translating the AM/PM portion.
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( inputTime , fTime ) ;
System.out.println( "lt.toString(): " + lt ) ;

ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z ) ;
System.out.println( "zdt.toString(): " + zdt ) ;

ZonedDateTime zdtEarlier = zdt.minusMinutes( 15 ) ;
System.out.println( "zdtEarlier.toString(): " + zdtEarlier ) ;

Instant instant = zdtEarlier.toInstant() ;   // Adjust from zoned to UTC. Same moment, different wall-clock time.
System.out.println( "instant.toString(): " + instant ) ;

java.util.Date d = java.util.Date.from( instant ) ;
System.out.println( "d.toString(): " + d + "\nCAUTION: The `Date::toString` method lies, applying the JVM’s current default tim ezone while generating the text from a value that is actually in UTC." ) ; ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/iClDQe).

> ld.toString(): 2019-02-19
>
> lt.toString(): 16:15
>
> zdt.toString(): 2019-02-19T16:15-05:00[America/New_York]
>
> zdtEarlier.toString(): 2019-02-19T16:00-05:00[America/New_York]
>
> instant.toString(): 2019-02-19T21:00:00Z
>
> d.toString(): Tue Feb 19 21:00:00 GMT 2019
>
> CAUTION: The `Date::toString` method lies, applying the JVM’s current default time zone while generating the text from a value that is actually in UTC.

To understand these values… Imagine at the end of her work day at 4 PM, Alice sitting in her New York office calls Bob’s cell phone. Bob is sitting at home in Reykjavík, [Iceland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iceland). Both Alice & Bob keep a call-log, so they each simultaneously glance up at the clock on their respective wall. What time-of-day does each write down in their own call-log?

Hints:

- [Iceland time zone](https://time.is/Reykjavik) uses an offset-from-UTC of zero, or UTC itself.
- [New York time zone](https://time.is/New_York) in the winter of 2018-2019 is five hours behind UTC.

## Future appointment

If this is a future appointment you are adjusting, you should subtract the quarter-hour from the `LocalTime` value, not the `ZonedDateTime`.

We keep future appointments *not* as a moment. If politicians were to change our clocks (change the offset-from-UTC used in our time zone on that date), for appointments we want to keep the same wall-clock time though a different moment (different point on the timeline).

```
LocalTime ltEarlier = lt.minusMinutes( 15 ) ;
…
ZonedDateTime zdtEarlier = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , ltEarlier , z ) ;
```

## Wrong class

You are using terrible the wrong classes. A `java.util.Date` represents a moment in UTC. So unless your appointment is for Reykjavík Iceland, you cannot use that class.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using terribly troublesome flawed date-time classes riddled with poor design choices and flaws. They were supplanted entirely by the *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310.

## *java.time*

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2019 , Month.FEBRUARY , 19 ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 16 , 15 ) ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z ) ;
```

Subtract 15 minutes. You get a new fresh `ZonedDateTime` object rather than changing the original, per the immutable objects pattern.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtEarlier = zdt.minusMinutes( 15 ) ;
```

Or as discussed above, for a future appointment:

```
ZonedDateTime zdtEarlier = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt.minusMinutes( 15 ) , z ) ;
```

### Converting

If you must have a `java.util.Date` to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, convert. You can convert back and forth between legacy and modern classes by calling new methods added to the old classes.

To convert to `java.util.Date` you need an `Instant`, the modern class representing a moment in UTC. You can adjust from a zoned moment to UTC merely by extracting an `Instant` from our `ZonedDateTime`. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.

```
Instant instant = zdtEarlier.toInstant() ;
Date d = java.util.Date.from( instant ) ;
```

Be aware that among the many flaws in [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html) is the poor design decision to have the [`Date::toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html#toString()) method dynamically apply a time zone to the UTC value while generating the text representing this moment. In other words, the **`Date::toString` method lies**, misrepresenting the UTC value as being zoned. Well-intentioned, but unfortunately causing endless pain and confusion to countless programmers trying to learn date-time handling. One of many reasons to avoid this class.

### Parsing

If starting from string inputs, parse. Use standard ISO 8601 formats for such inputs whenever possible. Otherwise, you need to specify a formatting pattern to match.

```
DateTimeFormatter fDate = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "M/d/uuuu" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2/19/2019" , fDate ) ;
```

Your input for time-of-day is malformed for the United States” cultural norms. The `am`/`pm` should be all uppercase, `AM`/`PM`. So call `String::toUpperCase()` before parsing.

```
DateTimeFormatter fTime = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( “hh:mm a" , Locale.US ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "4:15 pm".toUpperCase() , fTime ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thanks. But my input values are string. Im parsing from csv file.  like; appdate   = 2/19/2019
startTime = 04:15 pm

Comment: Thanks. I will try.

Comment: @Jack Tips: There is no “just do it” in date-time handling. Our own intuitive understanding of time works against us. Date-time handling is surprisingly tricky and slippery. Slow down, focus, don’t take any shortcut thinking you can get away without addressing time zone and offset-from-UTC issues, forget about your own parochial time zone, learn to think of UTC as the One True Time, and always use ISO 8601 formats when exchanging date-time values as text.

Comment: Text '04:15 pm' could not be parsed at index 6   Error occured at    LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse(startTime, fTime) ;   line    I dont live in US.

Comment: Properly localized, am and pm should be uppercase, AM & PM. So call the String method to uppercase your input before parsing.

Comment: The problem is that the formatter expects `PM` in uppercase, but it’s in lowercase in your string. Use a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` and its `parseCaseInsensitive` method. Or the hack, convert the string to uppercase before parsing. @Jack

Comment: Whoever downvoted, a criticism or reason would be most helpful.

Comment: I have chaged to uppercase. Error fixed now. But another error is  2019-05-14T20:00:00Z   at line   Instant instant = zdtEarlier.toInstant() ;  Time is worng after toinstant. It should be 04:00.   Why do we call  toinstant?

Comment: @BasilBourque  Im stuck here. There is an error about Instant method.

Comment: The `Instant` prints in UTC. 20:00 in UTC is the same point in time as 4 PM in New York, so isn’t it correct?

Comment: @Jack Imagine at the end of her work day at 4 PM, Alice sitting in her New York office calls Bob’s cell phone. Bob is sitting at home in Reykjavík, [Iceland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iceland). Both Alice & Bob keep a call-log, so they each simultaneously glance up at the clock on their respective wall. What time-of-day does each write down in their own call-log? (Hint: Iceland time zone uses an offset-from-UTC of zero, or UTC itself.)